# rest api wordpress creating a post with specific categories using c#

Tags: c#, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to add categories to my post use the module / package wordpressPCL and I can not seem to work it out does anyone have an idea on how to create posts with specific categories set.

error is that it doesn't accept an integer but the id is the integer my code.

```
private async Task mysite()
        {
            int[] genres = { 5 };
            var client = new WordPressClient("https://mysite/wp-json/");
            client.Auth.UseBasicAuth("user", "password");
            var post = new Post()
            {
                Title = new Title(textBox1.Text),
                Content = new Content(textBox2.Text),
                Categories = new Categories(genres)
            };
            await client.Posts.CreateAsync(post);
 
 
        }
```

ERROR IS ON LINE 10

First time using the library any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the int of the category first, and then you can place it in the URL that you call as part of your endpoint.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=3160
```

So you finish the URL with the included category number you have. To help you understand how things work, I suggest you use as I done the program postman, and try to get a post working to your site first.

```
{
    "title": "test post from postman",
    "content": "<p>This is a paragraph</p>",
    "status": "draft"
}
```

With the correct authorization, you can post this as raw json from inside postman, which proves that you system is setup correctly, and then you can implement the post and json encoding in your program.

Comment: spinstaz, thanks for the answer I still have a question...suppose the post has multiple categories how would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that from the URL, I tried a couple of variations in postman, and they didn't work; they either got the first one or the second one. I would like to know too, so hopefully, someone else can chime in.

Comment: @Zeeshanali, i figured it out, all you do is add a comma between numbers ``posts?categories=1,2``